# How do I apply styles to only the element I'm hovering on using Tailwind Typography and prose?

Tags: css, frontend, tailwind-css, markdown

I'm currently utilizing Tailwind typography and prose to style my markdown pages. I'm attempting to incorporate a hover effect specifically for images. However, I'm encountering an issue where the hover effect is applied to all images simultaneously, rather than just the one the cursor is over. Any suggestions on how to rectify this?

This is my code:

```
<article
    class="prose-img:w-full prose-img:rounded-2xl prose-img:object-cover prose-img:transition-all prose-img:duration-500 prose-img:ease-out prose-img:hover:scale-[1.01] prose-img:md:rounded-3xl"
>
```

I've applied a prose-img:hover style, expecting it to only apply to the actual element I'm hovering on. Instead, it will apply it too all images. It also seems to hovering on one image will actually activate all of them.

Comment: Just put the hover class on the element itself.

Comment: @possum unfortunately that's impossible as the content is being imported from markdown files.

Comment: The define a class with a child selector?  prose is not intended to be the final styling solution for any application.

Comment: @possum Can you please elaborate a bit more how I could utilize a child selector here to achieve my result, or how I can style content retrieved from markdown using Tailwind other than using prose? Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#ordering-stacked-modifiers), sometimes variant order matters:

> ### Ordering stacked modifiers
>
> When stacking modifiers, they are applied from the inside-out, like nested function calls:
>
> ```js
> // These modifiers:
> 'dark:group-hover:focus:opacity-100'
>
> // ...are applied like this:
> dark(groupHover(focus('opacity-100')))
> ```
>
> For the most part this doesn’t actually matter, but there are a few situations where the order you use actually generates meaningfully different CSS.

In your situation, you have `prose-img:hover:` which is conceptually like `prose-img(hover(…))`. This would evaulate to:

1. `hover:` – hover this element (the `<article>`).
2. Select all `<img>` elements within the `prose`.

Whereas really, it seems like you'd want the reverse, `hover:prose-img:`:

1. Select all `<img>` elements within the `prose`.
2. `hover:` – hover this element (the `<img>` element within the `prose`).

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1?plugins=typography"></script>

<article
  class="prose-img:w-full prose-img:rounded-2xl prose-img:object-cover prose-img:transition-all prose-img:duration-500 prose-img:ease-out hover:prose-img:scale-[1.01] prose-img:md:rounded-3xl"
>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/100">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/100?">
</article>
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes total sense and worked perfectly!